# StoreKit's paymentQueue(updatedTransaction:) updates transaction too soon?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm having a strange issue. I'm testing a few in-app purchases in the sandbox environment with sandbox testers created in iTunes Connect. I created both consumable and non-consumable products to test out. I only implemented the `productsRequest(didReceiveResponse:)` method to fetch the products from the App Store as soon as a user taps on them in my app. I added them to a `SKPaymentQueue` object, which was enough to make the app pop-up a user interface from the App Store which asks the user to log in with an Apple ID to confirm the purchase of the selected product. I remember this went perfectly the first time I did this. Back then, I wasn't logged in with any Apple ID on my device yet, so it was only after I completely walked through the entire process of confirming my purchase that the payment queue's delegate method `paymentQueue(updatedTransactions:)` was called. Inside this method I check what the status was updated to, and unlock the purchased content when the product was purchased:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    // Check what the transaction was updated to
    if transactions.last!.transactionState == .purchased {
        // Unlock purchased content here

        // Complete transaction and remove it from queue
        queue.finishTransaction(transactions.last!)
    }
}
```

The problem I'm constantly running into right now is that as soon as I call the `SKProductsRequest`'s `.start()` method, the method above immediately gets called and the transaction is update to `.purchased` EVEN THOUGH THE APP STORE PROMPT STILL HAS TO APPEAR. It results in the purchased content already being unlocked while the App Store still asks me to sign into my Apple ID to confirm my purchase. Did anyone else run into this issue? Does it have anything to do with the sandbox environment or the tester Apple ID? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this happening with a consumable or non-consumable product type.  If non-consumable, has that user ever purchased this product before?

Comment: @Paulw11 There is no difference between testing a consumbale and testing a non-consumable. This occurs on both products. Even when I created a new product in iTunes connect, this problem would still occur on that new product the very first time I purchased it. Besides, even if I did purchase it already, shouldn't I at least be logging into the App Store first before the App Store can tell me the product has already been purchased? Like I said, the method already gets called before I even log in, like right after I tap on the product I want to purchase.